# Experimental loss measurement of simple wireless link

Tags: rf, antenna, wireless, receiver

I connect a simple SDR to a spectrum analyzer (SA) and measure the output power. The SDR outputs a single tone at 1 GHz; between SDR and SA is a lowpass filter:

[image]

With gain setting GTX1 I measure -53.2dBm. With GTX2, -7.2dBm and with GTX3 I measure 12.8dBm.

Now I add a wireless link:

[image]

The two antennas are directional antennas with 10dBi gain (these: https://www.amazon.ca/APOHALO-800-2500MHz-Mobile-signal-antenna/dp/B07C91TFWP). They are placed exactly 1.2m apart, have full line-of-sight and are mounted on a tripod (Fresnel zone is clear).
I measure again the signal powers for the same three gain settings on the SDR GTX1, GTX2 and GTX3 and measure: -80.2dBm, -32.2dBm, -14.2dBm.

The difference in gain between these two setups is 27dB, 25dB and 27dB, respectively. So adding the 1.2m wireless link in between gives me **25-27dB measured attenuation**.

Now the path loss is 34dB (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free-space_path_loss). The two antennas have 10dBi gain each, so I would **expect a total loss of only** 34-10-10=**14dB**.

This is more than 10dB difference from what I measure.

What could the discrepancy come from?

(I am aware that the antennas themselves have losses but to my understanding they are factored into the gain: Gain=efficiency x directivity). And 13dB would be pretty large).

Comment: You say this: *Fresnel zone is clear* however, with high gain antennas the Fresnel zone can extend quite some distance and this means that your transmit antenna's Fresnel zone is being invaded by your receive antenna and you will get unexpected or hard to predict results.

Comment: Can I resolve this by placing the antennas farther apart? Which distance would be good to ensure no Fresnel zone related issues?

Comment: I was going to suggest that - you'll have to dig around to find how large the Fresnel zone becomes with directional antennas. I don't have that information to hand. Here is a useful link: https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=rx-1YAmPZycC&q=Fresnel+zone&source=gbs_word_cloud_r&cad=4#v=snippet&q=Fresnel%20zone&f=false

Comment: Hmm, it turns out that changing my setup is not as trivial due to space limitations in my lab. The first-order calculation would just give me 3mm maximum radius. Every point around the antennas is at least 30cm (100x) clear ... probably more. Can this really result in 13dB attenuation? Asked differently: The rest of my setup/assumptions look OK?

Comment: Typically, the Fresnel zone extends to about 1 lambda for a monopole so that's 33 cm and it will grow as the antenna directionality increases so I'm not sure where you got 3mm from?

Comment: do you have any actual datasheet for these antennas? They are almost certainly not constant gain over their whole bandwidth, and as usual, amazon marketplace is a bad place to buy electronic components, because chances of datasheets are slim to none, and nobody cares whether you'll buy from them again or not

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP has bought a device from a supplier that doesn't supply a datasheet. Device doesn't work as expected for application. Since no guarantees made by a datasheet can be expected, there's nothing to answer here: Get a device that comes with a datasheet that guarantees operation under the conditions that you need.